# searching an array with includes()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm searching an array of object's, more specific, checking if value of object matches search string (case insensitive). It throws me an error:
' element[0].id.includes is not a function':

```
let inputValue = event.target.value;
let arr= [];
this.rezerwacje.forEach(function(element) {
  if(element[1].toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
    || element[2].toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
    || element[0]['id'].includes(inputValue))
  {
    arr.push(element);
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure element is an array

Comment: `element[0].id` is not a string probably.

Comment: Is `element[0]['id']` a String or Array?

Comment: `element[0]["id"]` is neither a string nor an array.

Comment: id is an integer

Answer (score 1):

After clarification, that `id` is a number, you could convert it to a string ans use then `includes`.

```
element[0].id.toString().includes(inputValue)
```

Comment: The functionality is different. `==` checks for an exact match, `String.prototype.includes` checks for a substring within a whole string, and with an array, it is rather obvious what it does. In both cases, i don't know how `==` could be substituted for `includes`.

Comment: @Taurus, it looks like, that `id` is a number. for comparison with strict equality `===`, you need to convert an operand to number or to string for comparison. if you like to omit this step, you could use just equality `==`, because this tries to converts both operands to a comparable type. more here: [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: Why wouldn't OP use `==` in the first place if they didn't specifically have to use `includes` ? If you know about `includes`, then I think it is quite safe to say you know about the functionality of the equality operators as well.

Comment: @Taurus, actually we don't know the op's motivation.

Comment: id an a number yes, but I want to search the substring also, so i can't use ==

Comment: @Ziomski, you can convert `id` to a string an use `includes`.